# Intelligence Tools don't show up in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, toolbox

I need to use the "Points to Track" tool in ArcGIS Pro, but it does not show up when I search for it in the geoprocessing toolbar. I searched online and found that it is in Intelligence Tools. For whatever reason, the Intelligence Toolbox isn't available in my version of ArcGIS Pro. Do any of you know what the problem is, and howI can resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The Intelligence toolbar is an additional Esri Solution that you can choose to install when installing ArcGIS Pro (but which is not installed by default). According to [this Esri documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/install-and-sign-in-to-arcgis-pro.htm) while going through the installation process for Pro there should be an option to also choose to install ArcGIS Pro Intelligence.